# Code not setting text properly

Tags: java, android

I have a code that is supposed to check if a position is available or even needed. Here is my code:

```
if(!Objects.equals(PhotoEditor, "null")){
    if(Objects.equals(PhotoEditor, "N/A")){
        tvPhotoEditor.setText("Not Applicable");
        cbPhotoEditor.setEnabled(false);
    }else{
        tvPhotoEditor.setText(PhotoEditor + " Scheduled");
        cbPhotoEditor.setEnabled(false);
    }
} else {
    tvPhotoEditor.setText("Photo Editor Available");
    cbPhotoEditor.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Right now, it is pulling info from my CRM and the field for this was set to N/A as a test, however it returned the result "N/A Scheduled" which means it went to the else statement, and not the first if statement. How do I get it to go to the if statement instead

Comment: Thats not how you check for null -- Try -- if(!Objects.equals(PhotoEditor, null))

Comment: What is the type of `PhotoEditor`? could you try `if(Objects.equals(PhotoEditor.toString(), "N/A"))`?

Comment: Taso, the CRM passes a literal string of null for null objects, that's why I have it like that. But yes, I am aware that that is how I normally check for null.

Comment: Jean-François Fabre, it is already of the datatype String, here is how it was initialized: String PhotoEditor = intent.getStringExtra("PhotoEditor");  the intent was also a String value as well.

Comment: Are you sure there is no trailing whitespace in "N/A"?

Comment: bradimus, ok, that may have been the issue, it's working properly now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You only change your code with below to solve your problem

```
if(!Objects.equals(PhotoEditor, null)){
```

and you also can use

```
if(PhotoEditor != null)){
```

to achieve